# Update Query in mysql

Tags: mysql

folks

I have a table as attached

[image]

we need the dial code field as below

dialcode column as below

```
id dialcode
640 1684
641 16842 
642 168473
643 1758
644 1758284
645 1758285
```

Basically the dialcode field of parentid=0 should be updated in dialcode field along with number where parentid<>0

for eg id=641 then dialcode will be 16842.

Comment: What you have tried so far....

Comment: Will your data be any level depth or just two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..may be this is possible answer

```
update table3 t1 left join table3 t2 on t1.parentid = t2.id  
set t1.dialcode = CONCAT(t2.dialcode,t1.number) where t1.parentid<> 0
```